# How to I change text position on a frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Rather a specific request I can't seem to find any online documentation on:

I'm trying to change the position of the font on frames surrounding buttons. As shown below the text is currently centered above the button. I would like the text to be displayed to the right of the button.

[image]

Heres my code for the frames and buttons:

```
"""Button frames"""
constituent_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Fibre and resin data inputs", padx=2, pady=2)
ply_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Single lamina data inputs", padx=2, pady=2)
laminate_frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Complete ply stack data inputs", padx=2, pady=2)

"""Frame positions"""
constituent_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=50)
ply_frame.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=50)
laminate_frame.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=50)

"""Button definitions"""
constituent_button = Button(constituent_frame, text='Constituent', width=15, command=click_constituent)
ply_button = Button(ply_frame, text='Ply', width=15, command=click_ply)
laminate_button = Button(laminate_frame, text='Laminate', width=15, command=click_laminate)

"""Button positions"""
constituent_button.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=2)
ply_button.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2)
laminate_button.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=2)
```

Any advice or links to resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the button positing, try a mixture of padx and ipadx until you get what you need

Comment: Two issues with this:
The font automatically remains above the button rather than dropping to the side of it.
The font sticks to the top left corner of the frame rather than being justified to the right.

Comment: That's just how a Labeled Frame works. If you want text to the right of the buttons, you should create a regular label next to the button. Can you show a picture of how it should look?

Comment: I ageree with @tobias_k: you should probably just use a normal `Frame`, not `LabeledFrame`, and then add a label, for example: `Label(constituent_frame, text='...').grid(row=2, column=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `labelanchor` argument on the `LabelFrame` class to achieve this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

labelframe = LabelFrame(root, text="Hello", labelanchor=E)
button = Button(labelframe, text="BUTTON")
labelframe.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

possible values are the cardinal directions (NSEW) - tkinter has constants for these

[image]

Comment: Many thnaks for the solution!

Is there a way to make the same boarder span a group of widgets?

For example three buttons which share the same frame to categorise them?

Comment: sure thing - if it answers your question please accept it so others can find a quick solution to this same problem

Comment: And yes there is a way to do that, you simply need to add the elements you want to be in the labelframe to it by setting it as their "master" i.e.
`tkinter.Button(label_frame, text="Button1").pack()`
You can do this with as many buttons as you want and get them all under the same LabelFrame